# Why does the author define the integral of $f$ only for $f$ which is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function? Measure, Integration & Real Analysis Axler

Tags: real-analysis, definition, lebesgue-integral

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.

I am afraid that my question is stupid.

Definitions in this book:

> 3.1 **Definition** ***$\mathcal{S}$-partition***
> Suppose $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on a set $X.$ An *$\mathcal{S}$-partition* of $X$ is a finite collection $A_1,\dots,A_m$ of disjoint sets in $\mathcal{S}$ such that $A_1\cup\dots\cup A_m=X.$

> 3.2 **Definition** ***lower Lebesgue sum***
> Suppose $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ is a measure space, $f:X\to [0,\infty]$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function, and $P$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-partition $A_1,\dots,A_m$ of $X.$ The *lower Lebesgue sum* $\mathcal{L}(f,P)$ is defined by $$\mathcal{L}(f,P)=\sum_{j=1}^m \mu(A_j)\inf_{A_j} f.$$

> 3.3 **Definition** ***integral of a nonegative function***
> Suppose $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ is a measure space and $f:X\to [0,\infty]$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function. The *integral* of $f$ with respect to $\mu$, denoted $\int f d\mu$, is defined by $$\int f d\mu=\sup\{\mathcal{L}(f,P):P\text{ is an }\mathcal{S}\text{-partition of }X\}.$$

I wonder why the author requires $f$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function.
We can define the integral of $f:X\to [0,\infty]$ which is not an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable funtion.
I guess if $f$ is not an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable funtion, then the integral of $f$ doesn't have nice properties.

Comment: How do you define the inetgral of the characteristic function of a set $A$ if $A$ is not in the $\sigma-$ algebra?

Comment: @geetha290krm It seems the OP wants to define it with the same formulas. I think this definition implies $\int{\bf 1}_Ad\mu=\sup\{\mu(B)\mid B\in\mathcal S,\; B\subseteq A\}.$

Comment: Outer measure is not additive which makes integral not additive either.

Comment: The key is that if $f$ is  $\mathcal S$-measurable, then there is a increasing sequence of measurable simple functions which converges pointwise (uniformly if $f$ is bounded) to $f$. This gives nice properties to the definition of integral. This may not be the case if $f$ is not $S$-masurable.

Comment: See my answer on another similar question.  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4014486/442  You are right.  The property $\int(f+g) = \int f + \int g$ can fail for non-measurable functions.

Comment: geetha290krm, Anne Bauval, NewB, GEdgar, Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: @NewB I will reread the proof of Theorem 2.89 about approximation by simple functions.